# Xcode 10: Block-compressed payload operation failed

Tags: xcode

I want to install Xcode 10 Beta 6 on macOS 10.13.6 with the .xip format but in the expanding it shows the following error:

```
The operation couldn't be completed. Block-compressed payload operation failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using `xip -x`to extract the Xcode app manually.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by freeing up my MacBook Pro's internal SSD. It was simply out of space.